# Scheduled batch file exits when a batch files it calls exits

Tags: python, excel, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to take the input of a XLSX file and convert it to a CSV, then modify it to remove blank lines, remove unwanted lines, and fix formatting. This needs to be done once a day.

What I have started to do to attempt this is use a batch file to scan an input directory for an XLSX file. For each file it finds it will do the following

It then take the XLSX file and converts it to CSV using a batch script that calls Excel.Application in JScript

It then moves the processed file to a sub folder for archiving

Then it calls a python script to modify the file.

At the top it also maps a network drive, as the source folder is on the network and it seems that when the program was run from task scheduler it was unable to access the normal network maps (or so I was told, did not confirm this part myself)

Here is the top level batch script

```
net use Z: "\\network-path-to-folder"
Z:
for %%i in (*.xlsx) do ( "C:\Program Files (x86)\XLSX2CSV\converter.bat" "Z:\%%i" Sheet1 "C:\Program Files (x86)\XLSX2CSV\Output - CSV\%%i.csv" & move "Z:\%%i" "Z:\Archived XLSX\%%i" )
cd /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\XLSX2CSV"
C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe convert.py
```

The for line loops over every XLSX file in the source folder, then calls converter.bat with the variables [input file] [sheet] [output file], then moves the input file to a subfolder.

Here is converter.bat

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment



    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*

    exit /B /b %errorlevel%


@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */


var ARGS = WScript.Arguments;

var xlCSV = 6;

var objExcel = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application");
var objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(ARGS.Item(0));
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = false;
objExcel.Visible = false;

var objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(ARGS.Item(1))
objWorksheet.SaveAs( ARGS.Item(2), xlCSV);

objExcel.Quit();
```

The long and short of it is, the 2 lines starting with [cscript] and [exit] are batch lines. It starts executing on the [cscript] line where it calls the lower part of the script to convert a XLSX file to a CVS file using the verribles its passed. It then returns up and exits.

When I run this from the command prompt it works fine. The top batch script calls converter.bat that converts the file, then hands control back to the top batch script that then calls the python script to fix the file.

HOWEVER

When it is launched from the task scheduler it will call converter.bat to convert the file, not convert the file, then exit, specifically citing "exit /B /b 0" as the last executed command when I have it output to a log file.

Im thinking that once it reaches the [exit] line in the converter.bat script it exits out of all scripts run on that task, rather than exiting out of converter.bat and handing control back to the top script. But that is what /B is suppose to stop. Im not sure why it is not first converting the file.

You can't really use functions in batch scripts outside of using [call :function] with an [exit] at the end of the function. So is there some way to fix this?

Otherwise is there any better way to approach this?

Comment: Wow second time I have said this today.  When you run a batch file from another batch file, control is passed to the batch file that was executed.  If you need control to pass back to the parent batch file then you must use the `CALL` command. `CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\XLSX2CSV\converter.bat" ......`

Comment: No need to use the `NET USE` command. Especially since you don't seem to be deleting the mapping after.  Just use `PUSHD \\server\share\folder` and `POPD` to return back to the current working directory and get rid of the temporary drive mapping that `PUSHD` created.

Comment: `exit /B /b`? I always thought the `/b` switch was case insensitive....